# What is impression CTR, Request RPM, Impression RPM in admob

Tags: android, admob, ads, impressions

[image: admob]

I'm not getting this **Impression CTR** , **Request RPM**, **Impression RPM**.
how this all is calculated? and what should I do for more estimated earnings.

does higher CTR increase earnings?
will constantly showing ad in app (more impressions) will increase earnings?

Comment: Clicks/Impressions * 100 = Impressions CTR   
(112/1471) * 100 = 7.6
Estimated Earnings/Requests * 1000 = Request RPM 
(  6.82 % 2621 )* 1000 = 2.60

Comment: Hello akashay. Can you share, what is your CTR now, 11 months later? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @rootpanthera It is low as compared to that .. ~1% only

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Clicks/Impressions * 100 = Impressions CTR   (Click through rate)
(112/1471) * 100 = 7.6

Estimated Earnings/Requests * 1000 = Request RPM ( Revenue per thousand requests )
(  6.82 % 2621 )* 1000 = 2.60

Estimated Earnings/Impressions * 1000 = Request RPM ( Revenue per thousand Impressions )
Similar to above but replace requests with impression value.

I think your CTR is already too high as compared to normal which is usually less than 2%. 
No, Higher CTR doesn't promise higher earnings. Its the CPC ( Cost per click) that matters.

Also, showing more impressions in an app will not increase your earnings. The ad placement should be very comfortable for the user to check it out. 
If you provide advertisements in a proper way. User might use your app often hereby increasing retention. Thereby increasing real impressions of ads.

Comment: so Admob only pays for clicks? not for per thousand impressions?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise they are open to abuse.

Comment: so even the longer time the ad displayed , there's no value?

Comment: I'm quite sure AdMob pays for displayed ads. It says: "An impression is counted when at least 1 pixel of an ad is visible on a device's screen." ( 
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3269069?hl=en&ref_topic=3436430) And revenue is counted in "RPM" (Revenue per 1000 impressions)

Answer (score 1):

Most General questions that everyone is wants to know on how much download, the revenue would come . its all about ad mob ads show policy, the business market around the world generate account on ad mob as advertiser and developer as a publisher, advertiser gives their ads to ad mob in banner , interstitial form,rewarded video as they wants to promote their goods in different countries, and select price to show ,number of countries, and paid is detected on these basis , (more in plus given in ad mob policies) ads are showing on these basis that are promoted by advertiser for a specific territoriality, google takes money from advertiser and take the little percentage and then giving to publisher for ads monetizing means to developer, if the ads impression rate is high you will get more revenue.